# Issues with refunds for credit card payments

Tags: contributions, authorize.net

This has been a long standing issue for us.

We accept event registrations and accept payments with credit cards through Authorize.net. Many of our events have multiple options using price sets.

If someone registers for the event, and later needs to change the options lowering the fee, they need a refund. We can issue the refund manually without issue, but when we change their registration in CiviCRM the contribution fee changes to the new value and the status changes to pending refund, and we can't ever change it from that.

All our refunds happen manually out of the system, and we really need the pending refund contributions to be changeable back to complete when the refund is processed.

This really messes up our reporting for the event, and throws things off in a messy way.

Is there a way to resolve this so that we can track things as they should be?

What is the logic in restricting the change in that field? Since CiviCRM can't process the refund, and we need to do it offline, we should be able to change the status once we issue the refund.

Any help, thoughts, or ideas would be wonderful.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what version of CiviCRM you are using.

In 4.7 you need to record the refund against the registration record. This can be done at the time you alter the registration or by viewing the event registration later on.

In both case you will get a screen that clearly offers you chance to Record refund.  [image: event registration needing refund]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywfRT.png)

Comment: The version is 4.7.  Sorry I forgot to mention that.  I have not seen the option "Record Refund", and it is not showing up on the view or edit registration pages for us.  Is there something I need to do to make that show?  Or something I did that might have hidden it?

Answer (score 0):

In the Civicrm Sandbox (I used the WP based sandbox which is running civicrm version 4.7.29) I registered a contact for both events (Rainforest, Fall Fundraiser) and submitted CC payment. I then set the participant status to 'Pending refund' as shown above by JoAnne, and while no button for "Record Refund" is shown in the View panel, the actions for the fee showed View, Edit, more, and under more, 'Record Refund'. I selected Record Refund but 1) the panel displayed 'New Payment' and 2) I got the error 'No payment information found for this record' (screenshots included below) - seems like a bug, right?[image]